# Перенести загрузку скриптов в footer (Wordpress)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, cms, плагин, wp-plugin

Помогите перенести загрузку скриптов в footer:

```
   // Register scripts and styles in non-admin area only.
if (!is_admin()) {
    // Stylesheets
    wp_register_style('fotorama.css', FOTORAMA_PLUGIN_URL . 'fotorama.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('fotorama.css');
    // Scripts
    wp_register_script('fotorama.js', FOTORAMA_PLUGIN_URL . 'fotorama.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('fotorama.js');
    if (file_exists(WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/fotoramaDefaults.js')) {
        // Override defaults
        wp_register_script('fotoramaDefaults.js', WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/fotoramaDefaults.js');
        wp_enqueue_script('fotoramaDefaults.js');
    }
    wp_register_script('fotorama-wp.js', FOTORAMA_PLUGIN_URL . 'fotorama-wp.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('fotorama-wp.js');
}
wp_register_style('fotorama-wp.css', FOTORAMA_PLUGIN_URL . 'fotorama-wp.css');
wp_enqueue_style('fotorama-wp.css');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

пятый параметр `wp_register_script()` - это как раз указание для размещения скрипта в футере

Например:

```
wp_register_script(
    'fotorama-wp.js', // название скрипта
    FOTORAMA_PLUGIN_URL . 'fotorama-wp.js', // URL-скрипта
    array(), // названия скриптов, от которых зависит регистрируемый
    1, // версия регистрируемого скрипта
    TRUE // TRUE-размещение в подвале / FALSE-в заголовке
);
```

См. также: [описание](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) `wp_register_script()` в кодексе (по-английски)

Comment: wp_register_script('fotorama-wp.js', FOTORAMA_PLUGIN_URL . 'fotorama-wp.js'), '', '', true); не работает

Comment: @ВиталийШипилов и ошибок не выдает? скрипты подключаются? кеширующих плагинов нету?

Answer (score 1):

вот так заработало:

```
// Register scripts and styles in non-admin area only.
if (!is_admin()) {
    // Stylesheets
    wp_register_style('fotorama.css', FOTORAMA_PLUGIN_URL . 'fotorama.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('fotorama.css');
    // Scripts
    wp_register_script('fotorama.js', FOTORAMA_PLUGIN_URL . 'fotorama.js', array('jquery'), 1, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('fotorama.js');
    if (file_exists(WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/fotoramaDefaults.js')) {
        // Override defaults
        wp_register_script('fotoramaDefaults.js', WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/fotoramaDefaults.js', false, '1', true);
        wp_enqueue_script('fotoramaDefaults.js');
    }
    wp_register_script('fotorama-wp.js', FOTORAMA_PLUGIN_URL . 'fotorama-wp.js', false, '1', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('fotorama-wp.js');
}
wp_register_style('fotorama-wp.css', FOTORAMA_PLUGIN_URL . 'fotorama-wp.css');
wp_enqueue_style('fotorama-wp.css');
}
?>
```